# how many nodes can we add to windows failover clustering

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

In Availability group, for windows server 2012 only 4 replicas supported
from windows server 2016 8 replicas supported

Just like that how many nodes can add into our windows failover clustering?
Physical machines?
VM's?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of nodes in a failover cluster is 64 and it has been like that since Windows Server 2012, nothing has changed in this limitation since then.